# Inputting different variable types in one time in Java

Tags: java, user-input

I made a calculator in C++ and i'm trying to recreate it mirror-like in Java.

There were 2 double variables(`double a` and `double b`)for the 2 operands and a char(`char op`) to put in an if cycle, so for instace if `op = '+'` it will `cout << a << op << b << "=" << a+b << endl;`.

So i could write `12+2` in the console prompt and see `12+2=14` as output.

Now in Java i have to it one per line:

```
    Scanner Scin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("OPERATION>");
        a = Scin.nextDouble();
        op = Scin.next().charAt(0);
        b = Scin.nextDouble();
```

And so i have to write a value and press return each time. How can i input all in one time like C++, and maybe do it in one line of code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to press return each time, you can input `100 + 200`

Comment: Note: according to Java coding conventions, variables should never start with a capital, only with a lowercase letter, so your scanner variable should be `scIn` or `scin` (and even better, `inputScanner` - it's better when variable names have meaning). Names that start with uppercase are types (classes, interfaces, enums).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read in multiple variables at once using `Scanner`, you will have to read them in one at a time. However, there is a nice way to allow the inputs to occur without hitting enter each time or inputting a space: set a different delimiter! The default delimiter is whitespace (which includes newlines), but you could also set it to the word boundary `\b` from regex.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\b|\\s+");
```

Now you can read in `12+2` and it will split up the `next` calls where you want them, or you can continue to hit enter, or you can put spaces between the values. Your choice :D

To restore the delimiter to normal afterwards, use `in.reset()`.

**Edit**: To keep the word boundary from splitting the input at a decimal point, use the pattern:

```
(?<!\\.)\\b(?!\\.)|\\s+
```

Comment: Thank you alot! Now i have the mythical power of Java in my hands!

Comment: Err... not really, now it won't print the number with a decimal part, openin a post for that! :D

Comment: Ok, in that case the regex needs to check that the word boundary isn't next to a decimal point. I've updated my answer.